# Replace text in a string and ignore matches within HTML tags

Tags: php, html, string, full-text-search, matching

For a given string (typically a paragraph) I want to replace some words/phrases but ignore them if they happen to be surrounded by tags in some way. This also needs to be case-insensitive.

Using this as an example:

```
You can find a link here <a href="#">link</a> and a lot 
of things in different styles. Public platform can appear in bold: 
<b>public platform</b>, and we also have italics here too: <i>italics</i>. 
While I like soft pillows I am picky about soft <i>pillows</i>. 
While I want to find fox, I din't want foxes to show up.
The text "shiny fruits" is in a span tag:  one of the <span>shiny fruits</span>.
```

Lets say I want to replace these words:

- `link`: 2 occurrences. First in plain-text (match), second in an `A` tag (ignore)
- `public platform`: Plain-text (match, case-insensitive), second in an `B` tag (ignore)
- `soft pillows`: 1 plain-text match.
- `fox`: 1 plain-text match. It looks at complete words.
- `fruits`: Plain-text (match), second in `span` tag (ignore) with other text

For background; I am searching for phrase matches (not single words) and linking matches to a relevant page.

I want to avoid nesting HTML (no *links* within *bold* tags or vice-versa) or other mistakes (example: `the <a href="#">phrase <b>goes</a> here</b>`)

I tried a few approaches like searching against a sanitized copy of the text with HTML content removed, while that told me there was a match, I had a whole new problem of mapping that back to the original.

Comment: if you get the nodelist you can choose what nodes to parse cant you ?  Or is that what you are trying to avoid ?

Comment: well I did a few runs it appears to me you have to set rules for each tag in order to preserve nodes and then keep text nodes,  many lines of text, lmk if you find another way

Answer (score 1):

i've found mentions about [regex negative lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and after breaking my mind over got this regex (assuming you have **VALID** html tags pairing)

```php
// made function a bit ugly just to try to show how it comes together
public function replaceTextOutsideTags($sourceText = null, $toReplace = 'inner text', $dummyText = '(REPLACED TEXT HERE)')
{
  $string = $sourceText ?? "Inner text
  You can find a link here <a href=\"#\">link</a> and a lot 
  of things in different styles. Public platform can appear in bold: 
  <b>public platform</b>, and we also have italics here too: <i>italics</i>. 
  While I like soft pillows I am picky about soft <i>pillows</i>. 
  While I want to find fox, I din't want foxes to show up.
  The text \"shiny fruits\" is in a span tag:  one of the <span>shiny fruits</span>.
  The inner text like this <a>inner <b>inner text </b> here to test too</b>, event inner text
  <a inner text>omg thats sad... or not</a>
  ";
  // it would be nice to use [[:punct:]] but somehow regex thinks that < and > are also punctuation marks
  $punctuation = "\.,!\?:;\\|\/=\"#"; // this part might take additional attention but you get the point
  $stringPart = "\b$toReplace\b";
  $excludeSequence = "(?![\w\n\s>$punctuation]*?";
  $excludeOutside = "$excludeSequence<\/)"; // note on closing )
  $excludeTag = "$excludeSequence>)"; // note on closing )
  $pattern = "/" . $stringPart . $excludeOutside . $excludeTag . "/im";
  
  return preg_replace($pattern, $dummyText, $string);
}
```

example output with default params

```
     """
     (REPLACED TEXT HERE)\r\n
     You can find a link here <a href="#">link</a> and a lot \r\n
     of things in different styles. Public platform can appear in bold: \r\n
     <b>public platform</b>, and we also have italics here too: <i>italics</i>. \r\n
     While I like soft pillows I am picky about soft <i>pillows</i>. \r\n
     While I want to find fox, I din't want foxes to show up.\r\n
     The text "shiny fruits" is in a span tag:  one of the <span>shiny fruits</span>.\r\n
     The (REPLACED TEXT HERE) like this <a>inner <b>inner text </b> here to test too</b>, event (REPLACED TEXT HERE)\r\n
     <a inner text>omg thats sad... or not</a>     
     """
```

now step-by-step

1. no subsequent matches (we don't need `pillow` if have only `pillowS`)
2. if text is followed with any length sequence of `\w` word symbols, `\s` whitespaces or `\n` new lines and *allowed punctuation* that ends with opening close tag `</` - we don't need this match, and here comes negative lookahead `(?![\w\n\s>$punctuation]*?<\/)`. here we can be sure that match won't get into new tag because `<` is not in described sequence (`$excludeOutside` variable)
3. `$excludeTag` variable is basically the same as `$excludeOutside` but for cases when `$toReplace` can be html tag itself, for example `a`

###### pay attention that this code can't cover text with `<` or `>` and having those symbols can lead to unexpected behavior